# How to convert difference between dates into years using php

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp

I have dates in the format Start and end dates in the format(mm/yyyy). I want to display the difference of the dates in years, months.

example:

```
start date 09/2008
end date 07/2010
```

display should read

```
1 Year, 10 months.
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=difference+date+php

Answer (score 10):

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '09/2008');
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/Y', '07/2010');
$diff = $start->diff($end);
echo $diff->format('%y years, %m months');
```

Note that this requires PHP 5.3.0 or higher.